# Flutter/Dart: How to get list value where key equals

Tags: list, flutter, dart, key-value

I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time finding an answer for this, but I have a list that I need to get the value from where the key matches certain criteria. The keys are all unique. In the example below, I want to get the `color` where the `name` equals "headache". Result should be "4294930176".

```
//Example list
String trendName = 'headache';
List trendsList = [{name: fatigue, color: 4284513675}, {name: headache, color: 4294930176}];

//What I'm trying
int trendIndex = trendsList.indexWhere((f) => f.name == trendName);
Color trendColor = Color(int.parse(trendsList[trendIndex].color));
print(trendColor);
```

Error I get: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance getter 'name'. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here's how I'm adding the data to the list, where userDocuments is taken from a Firestore collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userDocument.length; i++) {
  var trendColorMap = {
     'name': userDocument[i]['name'],
     'color': userDocument[i]['color'].toString(),
  };
  trendsList.add(trendColorMap);
}
```

Comment: Just for checking, Can you make your dictionary look like this, if you have not done this `[{'name': 'fatigue', 'color': 4284513675}, {'name': 'headache', 'color': 4294930176}]`. And then try, and let me know?

Comment: I just added the code with how I'm adding the data to my list. Maybe you can tell me how to convert it properly? @Alok

Comment: Hey, I have answered your question, check that out and let me know

Comment: it may be a typo, but you have to write the `key`s and the `value`s in **'** or **"**. So as @Alok wrote, did you use his list?

Comment: Hey @SeriForte, he has made one more mistake, that calling the `key` in a wrong way to get the value, I have demonstrated the way of getting it right. Thanks for the support anyway :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess, I got what the problem was. You were making a little mistake, and that was, you're trying to call the `Map` element as an `object` value.

A HashMap element cannot be called as `f.name`, it has to be called `f['name']`. So taking your code as a reference, do this, and you are good to go.

```
String trendName = 'headache';
List trendsList = [{'name': 'fatigue', 'color': 4284513675}, {'name': headache, 'color': 4294930176}];

//What I'm trying
// You call the name as f['name']
int trendIndex = trendsList.indexWhere((f) => f['name'] == trendName);
print(trendIndex) // Output you will get is 1
Color trendColor = Color(int.parse(trendsList[trendIndex]['color'])); //same with this ['color'] not x.color
print(trendColor);
```

Check that out, and let me know if that helps you, I am sure it will :)